How to show an image on a XAML?
First I thought I needed to work with BorderBrushes, ImageSources, etc., but then I found out that a simple Image in a simple Border seems to be enough, as you can see in this answer.
This is the reason I thought that (screenshot of the design):

(The first one comes from the file "All_Colours.png" and the third from "Transparant.png", I don't care about the second brown square)
In XAML, it looks as follows:
<Border x:Name="box_Interior_Group_Color">
  <Image Source="/Company.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/All_Colours.png"/>
</Border>

...

<Border x:Name="box_Interior_Transparant">
  <Image Source="/Company.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/Transparant.png"/>
</Border>

... but when I run this, this is what I see:

You might think "you need to copy the files "All_Colours.png" and "Transparant.png" to your runtime directory", but that's the point:

I have copied those files to the runtime directory and to the "Modules" directory (I'm working on a DLL, located in a "Modules" subdirectory of the runtime directory), but that didn't save the issue.
There is nothing in the output window. I can imagine that Visual Studio wants to show those *.png files and fails, but in that case it must show some information in the output window.

What can I do?
Extra information: when I start the "Select Element" feature in the debugger, I am able to select the brown square, but the others look not even to be present on the XAML:
Hovering over the brown one (the brown gets slightly grayed):

Hovering over another one (everything looks slightly grayed, it's like those other borders are not even present):

When I open the "Live Visual Tree" feature and I select the mentioned boxes, they do appear, as you can see in following screenshots:
 and 

The syntax means that the image is compiled as Resource into the Company.Customer.Client assembly. So the JPG files need not be in the runtime directory, but this assembly containing the images.

@KlausGütter: thanks a lot for the confirmation. I was already hoping for that. But why don't I see that image when running my application?

@KlausGütter: I hope this question is not too stupid, but I have used PNG images while your refer to JPG images. I hope that's not the cause of my issue?

No, that is not a problem. Can you check in the properties of these files in the solution explorer if the compile action is set to "Resource"? Are you sure you have the latest version of the assembly in your folder?

@KlausGütter: you are right! The "build action" was set to "None", I've changed it into "Resource" and now it is running. This is great! Can you write this as an answer and indicate the procedure how to add a picture to a project in such a way that the "Build action" is set correctly from the first time? I'll accept that answer then.

The syntax Source="/Company.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/All_Colours.png" means that the image is expected to be compiled as Resource into the Company.Customer.Client assembly. So the image files need not be in the runtime directory, but this assembly is containing the images.
When adding an image file to the project Company.Customer.Client, make sure that the build action is set to "Resource".

